# Discord.js bot not reading messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a start with my first discord bot, just going with the basic 'Ping' 'Pong' bot for the moment. Unfortunately, it would appear that my bot cannot read messages, event though they have full admin privelages on the server itself, which means it can't even view commands.

A few additional notes:

- The bot initialises and comes online on Discord
- The bot DOESN'T show it's custom status
- The bot CANNOT read messages with it's prefix (Set as ; in config.json)

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
// Create Discord Session
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity('Running a test, hopefully.');
});

//Read Messages
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "ping") {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
        }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Other than the fact that you have 3 back ticks at the end of your code. Maybe you didn't place the proper prefix in your json file?

Comment: @Antony The backticks are because the instructions on wrapping code blocks don't make it clear that they should be on lines of their own, I fixed it for him.

Comment: Cheers @Barmar my bad there, and as for the json file, I am definitely using the correct prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Is the BOT even online? And as Antony said - is the prefix in config.json same as the one, that you are using?

Comment: thats right, there is a login command missing like `client.login(token)`

Comment: To answer your questions, yes and yes, config.json is in there with the correct prefix and token and yes the bot does come online.

Comment: @Archannad Can you show me the config.json? Don't forget to delete token before sending it.

Comment: Also, try using `client.user.setActivity('Running a test, hopefully.', { type: "PLAYING" });` instead and tell me, if it works now.